# binary representation shrinkage question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Suppose for a given number $n$, every operation is to add $+$ signs arbitrarily into its binary representation. Repeat this process $K$ times.

Prove:

- It is always possible to reduce the number to 1.
- Find the minimum $K$ in order to reduce the number to 1.

For example, for $n=13$, the operations can be
$$13_{10}=1101_2\to(1+101)_2=110_2\to(1+1+0)_2=10_2\to(1+0)_2\to1$$

In this example, $K=3$.

Comment: Does this work for $3_{10}$?

Comment: yes, it does of course. :)

Comment: You can do it in $2$ operations: $1101 \to 11+0+1=100$

Answer (score 1):

Is it always possible?  Yes.  Adding the digits will make the number smaller, because the number of digits must be at most $\log_2(n)+1$, where $n$ is the number.  Since these will be at most $1$, then the biggest the sum of the digits will be is $\log_2(n)+1$.  But $\log_2(n)+1\leq n$.  This holds for $n=2$ and an induction argument follows, I believe.  As well the sum of the digits must be positive.  So finite numbers will work their way down to one, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the true minimum is probably difficult. If you have $n 1$'s, putting plus signs everywhere will reduce it to no more than $\log_2 n$, so in $k$ operations you can deal with $2\uparrow \uparrow (k-1) 1$'s with the $-1$ from needing a step from $10$ to $1$